# Videopress Short Tags not working when pulling page into template

Tags: page-template

Videopress doesn't work for me when I drag multiple pages into a template e.g. pulling them in by their path name...

```
$page = get_page_by_path('Showreels/Excerpts');
```

Does anyone know how I can paste a videopress link directly into the php since the shortcode doesn't seem to work?

Comment: What do you mean 'not working'? Are you calling the shortcode manually, or just displaying the content? Post a little more code that explains what you're actually *doing* with `$page`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it... for anyone else having this problem...

1. Go to where your media is kept on your WordPress.com account i.e. Media  > Library
2. Go to edit the video and make sure that 'Display share menu and allow viewers to embed or download this video' - this is so that you can click the 'share' menu on the embedded video on an actual page, grab the embed link and paste it into your html code
3. Go back to your media page and disable the share menu again if you want to protect your videos.